# How to get user input as number and echo the stored array value of that number in bash scripting

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I have wrote a script that throws the output of running node processes with the cwd of that process and I store the value in an array using for loop and do echo that array.
How can I able to get the user enter the index of array regarding the output that the script throws and show the output against that input generated by user
Example Myscript

```
array=$(netstat -nlp | grep node)
for i in ${array[*]}
do 
echo $i
done
```

output is something like that

```
1056
2064
3024
```

I want something more advance. I want to take input from user like

```
Enter the regarding index from above list = 1
```

And lets suppose user enter 1
Then next output should be

```
Your selected value is 2064
```

Is it possible in bash

Answer (score 0):

First, you're not actually using an array, you are storing a plain string in the variable "array". The string contains words separated by whitespace, so when you supply the variable in the `for` statement, the unquoted value is subject to [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting)

You need to use the array syntax for setting the array:

```
array=( $(netstat -nlp | grep node) )
```

However, the unquoted command substitution still exposes you to [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion). The best way to store the lines of a command into an array is to use the `mapfile` command with a process substitution:

```
mapfile -t array < <(netstat -nlp | grep node)
```

And in the `for` loop, make sure you quote all the variables and use index `@`

```
for i in "${array[@]}"; do 
    echo "$i"
done
```

Notes:

1. arrays created with `mapfile` will start at index 0, so be careful of off-by-one errors
2. I don't know how variables are implemented in bash, but there is this oddity:

   - if you refer to the array without an index, you'll get the first element:

     ```
     array=( "hello" "world" )
     echo "$array"       # ==> hello
     ```
   - If you refer to a plain variable with array syntax and index zero, you'll get the value:

     ```
     var=1234
     echo "${var[0]}"    # ==> 1234
     ```

Comment: Okay, Thanks I got it but what about the second part?

Comment: Thanks for the response I've successfully wrote a script that can store process output with path and echo it with array index. But now I'm facing an issue it shows some process id as No process found whereas they are running at background and they even have a path (I have checked it by using pwdx "pid" on terminal)

Comment: Sounds like you need to ask a separate question with your code.